# How to highlight javascript variables in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, color-scheme

When using Visual Studio I find the 'Highlighted Reference' feature really useful: when you click on a variable the IDE will highlight all uses of that variable, making it easy to see where it is used in your code.

One can set the Highlighted Reference colour (`Tools > Options > Env > Fonts and Colors > Text Editor > Highlighted Reference`) and this works fine for my C# code however it doesn't change the highlighted colour of my javascript code. **Currently the javascript variables are highlighted in a very faint grey, which is very hard to see**. Does anyone know how I can change this colour for Javascript variable highlighting?

Comment: I also have this problem in VS2012.  Is it perhaps a bug fixed in 2013?

Answer (score 2):

This does sound like a bug in VS2012.
The following is a screenshot from VS2010, where the option you reference, correctly affects javascript files as well.

[image]